# Android-Stripe add missing parameters while account creating

Tags: java, android, api, stripe-payments

I was trying to implemented **stripe payment gateway**. Every thing is going fine. I was able to create connected account for the user in my stripe dashboard, but the problem is I'm missing following parameter

- Website
- SSN
- Industry

Now I want to know how to add these parameters while creating account.

I have add the screen shot from stripe dashboard and here is the **code**:

```
 Map<String, Object> dob =
                    new HashMap<>();
            dob.put("day", "12");
            dob.put("month", "1");
            dob.put("year", "1991");
            Map<String, Object> address =
                    new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, Object> address_pram =
                    new HashMap<>();
            address_pram.put("city", "Baton Rouge");
            address_pram.put("line1", "1 Calais Ave");
            address_pram.put("postal_code", "70806");
            address_pram.put("state", "Louisiana");
            address.put("address", address_pram);
            address.put("dob", dob);
            address.put("email", "ahmad@example.com");
            address.put("first_name", "ahmad");
            address.put("last_name", "bajwa");
            address.put("phone", "+12015551023");
            //address.put("website", "www.goldenkeystone.com");
            //address.put("industry", "");
         //   address.put("ssn", "000000000");
            Map<String, Object> acceptance =
                    new HashMap<>();
            acceptance.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            acceptance.put("ip", ipString);
            Map<String, Object> cardPayments =
                    new HashMap<>();
            cardPayments.put("requested", true);
            Map<String, Object> transfers = new HashMap<>();
            transfers.put("requested", true);
            Map<String, Object> capabilities =
                    new HashMap<>();
            capabilities.put("card_payments", cardPayments);
            capabilities.put("transfers", transfers);
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("type", "custom");
            params.put("country", "US");
            params.put("tos_acceptance", acceptance);
            params.put("business_type", "individual");
            params.put("individual", address);
            params.put("capabilities", capabilities);
            Account account = Account.create(params, requestOptions);
```

[image]

Note: If still question is unclear, I would be glad if you add your contribution.

Comment: That data and other sensitive information would be collected by Stripe during the onboarding via Account Links: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding It's not something that you can pass to the Accounts API.

Comment: OK you telling me there is a separate call for this?. If yes can you tell me the detail how to add that?

Comment: Here you go:https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web#create-an-account-link

Comment: put an answer with code and explanation.

Comment: @PaulAsjes thanks brother, Are you putting the answer or I am for future stripe users.

Comment: Good question. Stripe is great payment gateway.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data and other sensitive information would be collected by Stripe during the onboarding via Account Links: stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding

It's not something that you can pass to the Accounts API. See here for more information: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web#create-an-account-link

Comment: thanks for the solution, Even I was looking for it.